# how to convert this multiple inheritance to interfaces in Java?

Tags: java, c++, inheritance, interface

I want to implement the following multiple inheritance case:

(took from http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/117-multiple-inheritance/)

```
Person           Employee
   |_________________|
              |
           Nurse
```

at the end I want to print the salaries from Employee and Nurse. In C++ it is easy to be done by using multiple inheritance, but I have problems with Java.

I have the following codes:

```
public class Person{
    protected String name;
    protected int age;
    public Person(String name,int age){
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
    }
}
```

and the interface:

```
public interface Employee{
    public double getSalary();
}
```

and the class Nurse:

```
public class Nurse extends Person implements Employee{
    private double salary;
    public Nurse(String name, int age, double salary){
        super(name,age);
        this.salary=salary;
    }
    @Override
    public double getSalary(){
        return salary;
    }
}
```

but I do not have a clue how to make the Employee to print its salary, because it is an interface. I do not want to use other abstract class called Employee. How to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Java doesn't support multiple inheritance, or does it...???

Comment: no, but it can simulate it with interfaces

Comment: Java allows for a class to extend to another class. Basically, it isn't possible to have multiple inheritance.

Comment: You can't 'make an Employee print its salary', because, as you state, it's an ``Interface``. Interfaces merely define an API contract, they don't specify any kind of implementation of that API. You can never have just an ``Employee``, only things which *behave like* ``Employee`` says they will. However, I think your inheritance tree isn't right to begin with. Why is an ``Employee`` not a ``Person``? I don't really see why you needed multiple inheritance to begin with.

Comment: Why not have `Employee` extend `Person`?

Comment: I just want to convert the multiple inheritance case that I got from the web page I have linked

Comment: But our point is you *can't do that in Java*. It's explicitly forbidden. Java doesn't allow multiple inheritance. But since there doesn't seem to be any reason for there to be multiple-inheritance here in the first place, you should be able to get the same result by flattening your inheritance tree to ``Person->Employee->Nurse``

Comment: Avoiding multiple inheritance is a good thing, especially when there isn't any reason to do it as in your example. A Nurse *is* an Employee which *is* a Person.

Comment: Looking at that example tutorial, it's a TERRIBLE example of Multiple Inheritance. It contrives a toy example to simply show that it can be done, but doesn't do it for any actual REASON. An ``Employee`` doesn't particularly need to exist being independent of ``Person``. Just because C++ allows you to do something, doesn't mean you should do it. In fact, the end of the tutorial basically concludes as much.

Comment: Yeah, the Scanner/Printer/Copier example in that tutorial is a much better example of multiple inheritance than the badly contrived Teacher/Person/Employee example.  In what universe is an Employee not a Person?  Honestly, in over 20 years of programming, first C++ and later Java, I have only ONCE encountered a scenario where multiple inheritance would have been a reasonable thing to use.  Please, Layla, just skip sections 11.7 and 11.8 of this tutorial - they're no real use at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java allows multiple inheritance of interfaces only, so in order to implement that you have to define an interface for every class you'd like to combine and compose them in a single class by delegating all methods derived from the partial interfaces to their implementation.

**Person interface** - as you've defined it

**PersonImpl class**:

```
public final class PersonImpl implements Person {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    public PersonImpl(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

**EmployeeImpl class**:

```
public final class EmployeeImpl implements Employee {
    private final double salary;

    public EmployeeImpl(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Override
    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
}
```

**Nurse class** - composed from to other classes and delegates the functionality to them:

```
public class Nurse implements Employee, Person {

    private final Employee employee;
    private final Person person;

    public Nurse(String name, int age, double salary) {
        person = new PersonImpl(name, age);
        employee = new EmployeeImpl(salary);
    }

    @Override
    public double getSalary() {
        return employee.getSalary();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return person.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public int getAge() {
        return person.getAge();
    }
}
```

It's advisable to define an interface for every class you code in order to able that approach in the future.

Comment: No, please don't do this.  This is not inheritance, because you have to supply the definition of each method inside each class that uses it.  The whole point of inheritance is that an instance of type X "is an" instance of type Y, and therefore gets all the methods of type Y without having to redefine them.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that all employees are people (unless you are hiring monkeys!!), could you not chain the classes?

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name,int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

public class Employee extends Person {
    private double salary;

    public double getSalary(){
        return salary;
    }
}

public class Nurse extends Employee {
}
```

Comment: I never got Oracle's decision to allow classes to extend or be extended such that the definition contain absolutely nothing and are just type or tag specifiers.

Comment: @Casey that can actually be a useful thing to do with ``Exception`` classes though, to make your ``try/catch`` blocks more verbose and not have to parse error messages. I'd agree that in most other cases you don't really need an extra class if the definition is empty. It would make more sense in a language with multiple-inheritance so you can build a class out of mixins. It also makes sense for an ``abstract`` class as you're basically just building some base API set.